# Understanding/converting ES6 arrow function syntax when destructuring array to return first letter of each string element into a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, destructuring

I am looking at this code:

```js
//array to sample from (secretMessage array will say hello world)

const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

const secretMessage = animals.map(([i]) => i)
console.log(secretMessage)
```

What is the 2nd set of parenthesis and square brackets doing in `animals.map(([i]) => i)`? How would this look in old-style JavaScript?

Comment: If you want to see what map does, just make a `console.log` example and see what it logs out. `animals.map( ([i]) => i )` = `animals.map( function([i]){ return i } )`. It loops though each item and returns the nth element of each array, in this case `i = 0` so it's the first letter of each item in array.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here it is broken apart:

```
animals.map
```

Obviously looping through the animal array.

```
([i])
```

the parentheses are required if you wish to destructure something in the parameter list, and finally, `[i]` get's the first element of the "array", which is actually a string, thus returning the first letter.

This prints out "Hello world" letter by letter.

In "old-style" JavaScript this would be:

```js
animals.map(function(i) {
  return i[0];
});
```

Comment: If "old-style" is ES5 then `animals.map(function(s) { return s[0]})`?

Comment: @zer00ne sure... I don't think it matters that much, but I've edited my answer.